# Tizen Wearable Emulator could not proceed booting process

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am new with Tizen Wearable SDK, i have installed it successfully on my MAC machine. Now i have created a Emulator in Connection Explorer and try to run sample app on it. But unfortunately my emulator is not shown in Connection Explorer list. I am unable to run sample app on emulator. I right click on the emulator and try to open SDB, but it prompts that

> SDB is not ready. Please wait until the emulator is completely boot
>   up.

I wait for a long time but nothing happens. 
Anyone please help me. I want to see my emulator running.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Tizen Wearable SDK on Mac and Windows. The emulator takes 1-2 minutes to load the first  time you create an instance as it is unpacking the file system. After that, it's less than a minute to boot and appear in the Connection Explorer. Do you see the emulator window appear? It should have a digital clock face.

Which version of MacOS are you running? I was running Mavericks until early December when I updated to Yosemite on a MacBook Pro Retina.

Try to use sdb from Terminal. The command 'sdb devices' will point to the emulator, just as 'adb devices' does for Android targets. I don't have ~/tizen-wearable-sdk/tools on my $PATH but it may be necessary for you. sdb uses a port to communicate with the emulator. Are you running a firewall or port-blocker? [According to the docs](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/dev_env/commands.htm), *port 26101 is used by default if no port number is specified*.